# Mapping JSON data with React Hooks

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm working on a small project and I am trying to map data from a JSON file into my project.
In components with nested data, I keep getting an `let data = props.data["runways"];`.

#### data.json:

```
{
   "runways":[
      {
         "slot":"Area 1",
         "planes":[
            {
               "name":"PanAm",
               "number":"12345",
               "start":{
                  "time":1585129140
               },
               "end":{
                  "time":1585130100
               }
            },
            {
               "name":"PanAm 222 ",
               "number":"12345",
               "start":{
                  "time":1585129140
               },
               "end":{
                  "time":1585130100
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

### App.js,

I pass the JSON data as props:

```
import planeData from './plane_info.json'


const Container = () => {

    const [planeDataState, setPlaneDataState] = useState({})
    const planeData = () => setPlaneDataState(planeData[0].runways)
    return (
           <>
            <MyPlane planeInfo={planeDataState}/>
            <button onClick={planeData} type="button">Get Data</button>
           </>
       )
}
```

and finally, I want to bring my data into my component:

#### MyPlane.jsx

```
const MyPlane = (props) => {
    let data = props.data["runways"];
    if(data)
        console.log(data, 'aaa')
        return (
            <>
                {
                    data ? (
                        <div>
                        <span>{props.planeInfo.name}</span>
                        <span>RAIL TYPE: {props.planeInfo.type}</span>
                        </div>
                    ) : <h6>Empty</h6>
                }
            </>
        );
}
```

According to the error message, the problem occurs at this line of code: `let data = props.data["runways"];` However, I believe that I am passing the data for runways from the JSON file.
I've never worked with React Hooks to pass data, so I'm confused about why this error is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `const planeData = () => setPlaneDataState(planeData[0].runways)`

In this line, `planeData[0].runways` will be `undefined` according to the json file which you have shared.

Instead try setting and passing entire json object, ie,

`const planeData = () => setPlaneDataState(planeData)`

Try this, And then inside `MyPlane.jsx` component, `let data = props.data["runways"];` this won't be `undefined`. So , the error won't come.

Answer (score 2):

In order to map effectively over the JSON data it's necessary to understand how that data structure is composed.

If you're unsure, using [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) is a great way to get the "bigger picture" and then decide what exactly is it that you want to display or pass down as props to other components.

It appears you wish to get the plane data (which is currently an array of 2 planes). If so, you could first get that array, set the state, then map over it to display relevant info. Perhaps like this:

```js
const data = {
  "runways":[
     {
        "slot":"Area 1",
        "planes":[
           {
              "name":"PanAm",
              "number":"12345",
              "start":{
                 "time":1585129140
              },
              "end":{
                 "time":1585130100
              }
           },
           {
              "name":"PanAm 222 ",
              "number":"12345",
              "start":{
                 "time":1585129140
              },
              "end":{
                 "time":1585130100
              }
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
}

function App() {

  const [ planeData, setPlaneData ] = React.useState(null)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setPlaneData(data.runways[0].planes)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* {JSON.stringify(planeData)} */}
      {planeData && planeData.map(p => (
        <p key={p.name}>
          {p.name} | {p.number} | {p.start.time} | {p.end.time}
        </p>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Juan Marco,  this was a really clear explanation and I learned something new also.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning there is no data in `props.data['runways']` (also you can use `props.data.runways`, I guess you come from another language like Python as of this syntax that you are using), because you sent the request at first, it takes time for request to be satisfied, so you need to check in your `<MyPlane />` component to see if there is a `runways` key in data and then proceed to render the component, something like below:

```
const MyPlane = (props) => {
    const data = props.data
    return (
      <>
        {
          data.runways
            ? <>
                ...your render able items that you wrote before
              </>
            : <p>There is no data yet!</p>
        }
      </>
    )
}
```

Also please note that you might return something from component. At your case your render is inside the `if(data){...}` statement! what if the condition was not satisfied? which is your current error case !

**NOTE:** please check that you are passing your `planeDataState` as  `planeInfo` prop to the child component, so you might have something like:

```
const data = props.planInfo
```

to be able to use the `data` variable that you've defined before the `render` part.